# how to create a table which displays the results of an sql query

Tags: php, sql

I'm looking to create a table in php which displays the results of the following query:

```
SELECT users.id, SUM(votes.vote) AS TotalVotes
FROM users
LEFT JOIN nodes
INNER JOIN votes
ON nodes.id = votes.node_id
ON users.id = nodes.user_id
GROUP BY users.username
ORDER BY TotalVotes DESC
```

I've used other areas of this site to put together the above query and i've checked it in PHP My Admin to see what results it throws out, and it works how i'd like. But as i've never used sql before i have no idea how to turn this query into the resulting table that would be displayed in php on a webpage.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
Here you will find all you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many tutorials and resources about creating tables from mysql data with php statements; have a look around and give some of them a try. If you are having a specific issue, tell us what it is and we'll try to help. Here are a couple that popped up on google:

http://sudobash.net/web-dev-populate-phphtml-table-from-mysql-database/

http://davidwalsh.name/html-mysql-php

http://www.kavoir.com/2009/06/mysql-php-display-mysql-table-fields-and-data.html